# How to create Interval Timer with JavaScript and HTML which should work in iOS browsers?

Tags: javascript

The interval timer should take inputs in numbers (seconds) and after completion of given seconds, it should play a beep sound (The beep sound should support in iPhone browsers also).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `beep` audio. Embed it in your page and call that every 30 seconds. You do it this way:

```
<script>
function PlaySound(soundObj) {
  var sound = document.getElementById(soundObj);
  sound.Play();
}
</script>

<embed src="beep.wav" autostart="false" width="0" height="0" id="beep"
enablejavascript="true">
```

And then call it like:

```
setInterval (() => { PlaySound("beep"); }, 30000);
```